# Tests failing because fixtures are not present

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Django version 1.3.

I am new to Django unit testing. I have written my first test but it fails because my login isn't working. I'm quite sure the reason for this is that the database doesn't contain my user account which is supposed to be provided by the `auth` fixture.

The code I've written is:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class OrderCreateTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['auth']

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def testSelectProduct(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(user='chris', password='password'),
            'Unexpected login failure.')

        response = self.client.get('/order/new/')

        print response

        self.client.logout()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def runTest(self):
        pass
```

The test failure I'm getting is:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_proj')...
Creating tables ...
...
Running post-sync handlers for application admin
...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installing index for admin.LogEntry model
...
Running post-sync handlers for application admin
...
Loading 'initial_data' fixtures...
Checking '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/fixtures' for fixtures...
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/fixtures'.
...
Checking absolute path for fixtures...
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No xml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No json fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No yaml fixture 'initial_data' in absolute path.
No fixtures found.
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_proj')...
testSelectProduct (orpheus.orders.tests.ordercreate.OrderCreateTest) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: testSelectProduct (orpheus.orders.tests.ordercreate.OrderCreateTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/ordercreate.py", line 24, in testSelectProduct
    'Unexpected login failure.')
AssertionError: Unexpected login failure.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 2376.829s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_proj')...
```

Snippet from my settings with the db:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'project',
        'USER': 'project',
        'PASSWORD': 'projectdb',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_project' } }
```

I've stepped through the test code and I can see that it's finding my fixture `auth` and it's saving the data it finds... somewhere. I've suspended the test to drop into mysql and queried the relevant tables but they all stay empty (the test code has been skipping the sections dealing with transactions so I'm confident that i'm not supposed to wait for a commit).

What am I doing or not doing that keeps my fixtures from loading correctly?

**EDIT:** I had the brilliant idea to test loading the fixture and it succeeded:

```
$ ./manage.py loaddata auth
Installed 8 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

However, this doesn't give me any ideas on how to fix the fixture loading.

**EDIT:** supervacuo provided a clue when he suggested I try this:

```
./manage.py testserver -v 2 auth.json
```

The output is largely the same except that it correctly loads the fixture (mysql confirmed it):

```
...
Installed 8 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.3, using settings 'project.settings'
Running django-devserver 0.1.4
```

I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Where (in the filesystem) is `auth.json`? (Or whichever file format you're using?)

Comment: It is json. It's in the app directory for authentication, `<authentication app>/fixtures/auth.json`

Comment: Do you have a module in your project called `auth`? If so, and you have `django.contrib.auth` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, that could result in a naming collision. Hence, it's looking in contrib.auth for fixtures that don't exist, as there is no initial_data.json in django.contrib.auth.fixtures

Comment: Are you sure it finds your fixtures? Your test output seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: It is finding the fixture: I've stepped through the code in the Eclipse debugger and it actually compiles the correct SQL for the data in the fixtures, the data just doesn't show up in the database.

Comment: @Brandon: I do have `django.contrib.auth` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` as well as our own `authentication` app (I think its purpose is to add functionality to `django.contrib.auth`). I tried renaming `auth.json` to `authentication.json` and pointing my fixture at it `['authentication']` but this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you really sure, that the fixtures are found? The testrunner states 'No fixtures found'. So the fixtures do not seem to be loaded.

Comment: You're right to focus on that message: I did too. But that message is generated by `syncdb` when looking for `initial_data` fixtures, not the test fixtures. I'll update with the verbosity turned up to clarify that.

Comment: @phasetwenty interesting update! See my updated answer for more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was completely different from what it looked like. In my test I wrote:

```
    self.assertTrue(self.client.login(user='chris', password='password'),
        'Unexpected login failure.')
```

When the keyword arg should instead be `username`. I followed the red herring of missing data in the database, which is explained by [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.TestCase).

Thanks to mlavin in #django for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it has something to do with the test database (as your initial instinct suggested). If you look at [the relevant code from Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/test/testcases.py#L464), it just runs `loaddata` internally:

```
# django/test/testcases.py
if hasattr(self, 'fixtures'):                                           
    # We have to use this slightly awkward syntax due to the fact   
    # that we're using *args and **kwargs together.                     
    call_command('loaddata', *self.fixtures,                            
                 **{'verbosity': 0, 'database': db})
```

Thus, if `loaddata` works outside the test (as it apparently does), the problem must lie elsewhere. Given that it works with `./manage.py testserver`, I suspect that something in your codebase is inspecting `sys.argv` for `test` and modifying your database settings in such a way that the fixture is ignored. Could you `grep` across your project for `test` in unexpected places? I've got a section in `settings.py` like this:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:                              
    # Switch to sqlite for tests (it's *way* faster)                              
    DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: First useful clue! I don't know what to do with it, though. Updating my post with the relevant results.

Comment: Been running `grep` looking for something like this, but nothing is showing up. Going to keep looking though.

Comment: @phasetwenty hmm, OK. Another idea might be to step into `test/testcases.py` with `pdb` and see what `self.fixtures` and `db` look like.

Comment: `self.fixtures` is right but I can't get enough information out of `db`. It will tell me that it's connected to something on the localhost (as it should be) but I can't tell the database name.